# How can I copy content from my SD Card to my PC?

Tags: factory-reset, boot-loop, external-sd

I have an LG Marquee on Boost Mobile and recently my phone started to boot loop. I had not backed up my micro SD Card contents and am afraid I could lose them with my phone acting up like this. Each time my media scanner runs at start up, the phone reboots again, so I cannot access my media content in time to salvage it.

A user on here gave me the idea to buy an SD Card reader, put the contents of my SD Card onto my PC and copy them onto a new card. Then I could insert the new card into my phone and factory reset it in order to save my media content.

My question in a nutshell is: What is the process of copying content from an SD Card onto a PC, and then copying this content to a new card?

My second and last question is: Once I move the contents of my current SD Card onto my PC and copy them to a new SD Card, will my factory-reset phone take the new card and load the contents?

Comment: Remark to your second question: A factory reset is not required just for changing the card, the new card will be recognized without such. Keep in mind that a factory reset would delete all your content and the apps you've installed -- so that's rather a "last ressort" when having trouble with the phone, to rule out software problems.

Comment: @Izzy I appreciate the info. I would've ended up resetting my phone unnecessarily had you not told me that, so thank you!

Comment: Also see my answer on [your other question](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/40574/16575): formatting the card before obtaining its contents is a bad idea as well, as formatting would destroy the contents and leave nothing to obtain!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Answer to your first Question:*

No specific processes needed. When You Connect your SDcard to PC via SDcard reader, you can see a new drive is mounted on you PC. Just copy necessary files to PC and similarly copy same files to new SDcard.

*Answer to your first Question:*

Yes. your mobile will recognize your new SDcard when you mount it to your mobile.

Comment: I appreciate your help. It's much easier than I thought. Thank you.

Comment: Just mark as answer if it was what you expected.