# Do you have to reformat an SD Card before you can copy its contents to your PC?

Tags: boot-loop, external-sd, formatting

My phone has been stuck in a boot loop and I need to safely retrieve the contents via card-to-PC transfer, then PC-to-new card, then new card-to-phone, etc. I read somewhere on here that **you must reformat your SD card before you can connect it to your PC to copy its contents. Is this true?**

If so, **will I lose my stuff from reformatting my card?** Every time I've tried reformatting my card, I get a dialog box that tells me all my card's contents could be destroyed if I go ahead, so I refrain.

Seems like it would be pointless to try and retrieve my card's contents if I must destroy them first. I'm fairly new to this stuff, so please excuse my lack of knowledge for it.

Also, once I get all of my content into my new SD card, **do I need to format the new card when inserted in my phone?** I notice that whenever I put an SD card with files on it into a new phone, I get a prompt saying that all contents could be destroyed if I format, even though I want these files on my phone and certainly *not* destroyed.

Thanks for any and all questions answered, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you **MUST NOT** reformat it *before* copying! Formatting a storage device means to *prepare* it to hold files, and it will *delete everything on it* (see the [tag wiki of the formatting tag](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/formatting/info) for details). So yes, formatting woul imply losing all contents on the formatted device (in this case, from your SDCard).

New cards usually come pre-formatted, so there's no action needed either: Simply insert and enjoy. I never heard a device prompting you to format a newly inserted card, and I've had some of them. Of course, a warning is issued when you manually select to format a card, so you do not accidentally fall into such a trap.